# Could not see updated value while debugging ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I have used same command button Click event for both Insert, Update functionalities.

I'm checking with the url-querystring to achieve this functioality.
If the url-querystring is null then the page is meant for insert.
If the url-querystring is NOT null then the page is meant for update.

The code is shown below, but the update functionality is not working. When I debug the page, I understood that the new updated value is not presenting in the debug window. I have modified CR_TITLE and debugged. The new value is not coming in the debug. What is the problem?

```
    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ChangeRequest changeRequest = new ChangeRequest();
            changeRequest.CR_REF_NO = txtCRRefNumber.Text.Trim();
            changeRequest.CR_TITLE = txtCRTitle.Text.Trim();
            changeRequest.ORIGIN1_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOrigin1.SelectedValue);
            if (Request["ecr"] == null)
            {
                (new ChangeRequestBLL()).InsertECR(changeRequest);

                ((BLMSite)this.Master).ErrorText = string.Empty;
                ((BLMSite)this.Master).MessageText = "Record inserted successfully";
            }
            else if (Request["ecr"] != null)
            {
                (new ChangeRequestBLL()).UpdateECR(ecrRefNo, changeRequest);

                ((BLMSite)this.Master).ErrorText = string.Empty;
                ((BLMSite)this.Master).MessageText = "Record updated successfully";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ((BLMSite)this.Master).ErrorText = ex.Message;
            ((BLMSite)this.Master).MessageText = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Edit: I need to put this code inside (!Page.IsPostBack) condition. This is where I have committed mistake. Adding of this statement solved my problem.

Comment: Are you saying that txtCRTitle.Text is empty, or that after you set the CR_Title value it is still empty on your changeRequest object?

Comment: Sorry for my mis-communication.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Value should already present in txtCRTitle.Text since the page has been opened in Update mode. Now, I have modified the value in this txtCRTitle.Text, kept breakpoint, and clicked on "Update" button. Now, when I inspect the value inside the variable, I could not see updated value, but the old value.

Comment: I understand that you are filling in a value in a textbox and doing a postback. But when you say "I inspect the value inside the variable", are you talking about the txtCRTitle.Text value or the changeRequest.CR_TITLE variable? I ask to know whether the correct value is missing even from your textbox control on postback (which points to one possible problem) or is only missing inside your ChangeRequest object (which points to another problem).

Comment: Thank you very much. With your above question, I got some vague idea on some logic. I have added !Page.IsPostBack condition in the page load, and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just logic problem.

I handled the code just by setting iside !Page.IsPostBack condition and the problem is got solved. Hence, logic cannot be shown.

Thanks.